# What is the correct way to position the main content around appbars and drawers in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui for a lot of React apps. I'm using the responsive drawer + the appbar for a project and I'm confused about how best to position content around these navs. Do you just take your main content and put big top and left margins? Is there a better way to do this sort of thing ?

On my grid now, I have:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: "0 20px",
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    marginLeft: 230   
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Dashboard example](https://material-ui.com/page-layout-examples/dashboard/) in [Page Layout Examples](https://material-ui.com/page-layout-examples/) ([code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/page-layout-examples/dashboard/Dashboard.js)).  This is a very good example and should help you arrive at a layout for your app.

Regarding the height of the `AppBar`, the approach is interesting.  Rather than specifying a static top margin or padding, they're inserting a `div` that is styled to be as tall as the `AppBar` (since its height is responsive and will be different for various viewports):

```html
<div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
```

The class `appBarSpacer` is defined in the stylesheet and uses the toolbar mixin, which exports the exact responsive behavior that is used in `Toolbar` (and by extension, `AppBar`):

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  // ...
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  // ...
});
```

The effect is that there will always be enough space above the main content to push it beneath your `AppBar`.